# Printing the max and min values with pandas Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to write a function that prints out all the max and min values and their indexes for the specified columns in the `input.csv` file. The columns I want to return the max values of are referenced in the `max_columns` variable and the one to return min values are in the `min_columns` variable. However it doesn't go through the whole array values as intended I tried to do it with pandas howver it does not work. The code down below was achieved from my previous post:

input.csv file:

```
element,LNPT,SNPT,NLP,NSP,TNT,TPnL,MxPnL,MnPnL,MxU,MxD
[ 2.  2. 30.],0,0,4,4,8,-0.1,-0.0,-0.1,17127,-3
[ 2.  2. 40.],0,0,2,2,4,0.0,-0.0,-0.0,17141,-3
[ 2.  2. 50.],0,0,2,2,4,0.0,-0.0,-0.0,17139,-3
[ 2.  2. 60.],2,0,6,6,12,0.5,2.3,-1.9,17015,-3
[ 2.  2. 70.],1,0,4,4,8,0.3,0.3,-0.0,17011,-3
```

Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('STDOutputs_Q1.csv')
max_columns= np.array([1,2,3,7,8,10])
min_columns = np.array([4,5,6,9])

def max_vals():
    max_index = df[max_columns].idxmax()
    max_values = df[max_columns].max()
    return results, index
    
def min_vals():
    min_index = df[min_columns].idxmin()
    min_values = df[min_columns].min()
    return results, index

max_values, max_index= max_vals()
min_values, min_index= min_vals()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max_columns` and `min_columns` hold integer indexes, so you should `iloc` them as `df.iloc[:, max_columns]` and `df.iloc[:, min_columns]`:

```py
max_columns = np.array([1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 10]) # numeric indexes
min_columns = np.array([4, 5, 6, 9])

def max_vals():
    max_index = df.iloc[:, max_columns].idxmax() # so not df[max_columns]
    max_values = df.iloc[:, max_columns].max()
    return max_values, max_index

def min_vals():
    min_index = df.iloc[:, min_columns].idxmin()
    min_values = df.iloc[:, min_columns].min()
    return min_values, min_index
```

Alternatively you could define `max_columns` and `min_columns` by name, in which case `df[max_columns]` and `df[min_columns]` would work:

```py
max_columns = ['LNPT', 'SNPT', 'NLP', 'MxPnL', 'MnPnL', 'MxD'] # named indexes
min_columns = ['NSP', 'TNT', 'TPnL', 'MxU']

def max_vals():
    max_index = df[max_columns].idxmax() # so not df.iloc[:, max_columns]
    max_values = df[max_columns].max()
    return max_values, max_index

def min_vals():
    min_index = df[min_columns].idxmin()
    min_values = df[min_columns].min()
    return min_values, min_index
```

Comment: It gives me the error `IndexError: .iloc requires numeric indexers, got ['LNPT' 'SNPT' 'NLP' 'MxPnL' 'MnPnL' 'MxD']`

Comment: The two options are mutually exclusive. Use `df.iloc[:, max_columns]` if `max_columns` contains column numbers (like your original `max_columns`). Use `df[max_columns]` if `max_columns` contains column names. That error means you tried `df.iloc[:, max_columns]` with column names.

Comment: @tonyselcuk I edited the two options to make them more explicit